# Ubuntu won't boot on Asus Zenbook UX431

Tags: system-installation, asus

Asus Zenbook UX431FA i5-8265U CPU, Integrated Intel UHD Graphics 620, Dual boot with windows 10

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS don't boot. I either get stuck on a blank purple screen, or right now, a blank purple screen flashes before going to a blank black screen. I got this laptop in August and still haven't figured out how to fix this. Replacing "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" or booting in recovery mode followed by safe graphics mode does allow it to boot, but then there are issues with display resolution which are bad enough to make certain windows unnavigable.

This problem has been posted and solved elsewhere, however they don't work for me or involve a Nvidia graphics cards which my laptop does not have. I have upgraded BIOS twice and neither time solved the problem. Entering *dis_ucode_lds* does nothing.

Comment: We don't support Mint, there is no Ubuntu 18 (Ubuntu desktop and server releases are *yy.mm* in format, only specialist releases like Ubuntu Core use the *yy* format but they don't have gui being intended for headless appliances and are snap based), and no Ubuntu 19 (*yy* releases are snap based and only come out on even years).

Comment: Have you tried to disable Safe Boot?

Comment: Yes, I tried disable safe boot but the result is same black screen.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure it isn't the image? Try to boot live from another machine. that will give you an answer. Let me know. I just had to rewrite mine a week ago. All it did was sit in a drawer, but somehow it corrupted. Mine showed different symptoms, though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved with solution I found in https://blog.revant.me/blog/asus-zenbook-ux431fa-linux-display/

> First boot with `nomodeset` to get access to system.
>
> As root change working directory to `/lib/firmware/edid/`
>
> ```
> cd /lib/firmware/edid
> ```
>
> Download the edid file
>
> ```
> wget -c https://github.com/akatrevorjay/edid-generator/raw/master/1920x1080.bin -O ncp.bin
> ```
>
> As root modify the kernel boot parameter and update grub menu
>
> ```
> nano /etc/default/grub
>
> ###
> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash drm.edid_firmware=edid/ncp.bin"
> ###
>
> update-grub2 # for ubuntu
> ```
>
> Reboot and the display and brightness control will work